# Install oracle 11g2r2 driver for nodejs 0.10.20

Tags: oracle, node.js

I want to connect oracle 11gR2 and node.js 0.10.20. 
I use [this package](https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-oracle) but i dont understand this part of installation process. 
Can you explain it?

```
# Replace /opt/instantclient_11_2/ with wherever you extracted the Basic Lite files to
echo '/opt/instantclient_11_2/' | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle_instant_client.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that you downloaded and unpacked oracle driver into location **/abc/def**, you shall execute following commands

```
echo '/abc/def' | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle_instant_client.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

to add the shared object files to the ld cache